# Passing parameters when initializing a library in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am really new to Codeigniter, and just learning from scratch. In the CI docs it says:

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
$this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
```

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Someclass {

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        // Do something with $params
    }
}
```

Can you give me simple example how to pass data from controller to external library using array as parameters? I'd like to see a simple example.

Comment: And the example is in your question ..`$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red'); $this->load->library('Someclass', $params);` does it

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: I don't agree with or understand your first comment, can you clarify? Why shouldn't you pass parameters to the constructor?

Comment: @WesleyMurch We cannot access constructor directly,right! Like,passing parameters into it from a uri. I never tried it though. And i've never seen anyone doing so. I may be completely wrong. The moment i saw it in the OPs question made me feel like that. can we do it? Please explain & sorry for my bizzare comment

Comment: CI libraries are just PHP classes, you can do anything you want with them, including calling `__construct` manually. I can't understand your question at all, of course you can pass in arguments to the constructor.

Comment: @WesleyMurch TFYI. I was seeing it as a method which can't be called from a uri. I forgot the basic thing that it can be called manually inside the constructor :O

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. No only controllers can be "accessed directly" from the URI, but of course you can do anything you want after that.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yup, Thanks for reminding it :)

Answer (score 8):

All Codeigniter "library" constructors expect a single argument: an array of parameters, which are usually passed while loading the class with CI's loader, as in your example:

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
$this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
```

I'm guessing you're confused about the "Do something with $params" part. It's not necessary to pass in any params, but if you do you might use them like this:

```
class Someclass {
    public $color = 'blue'; //default color
    public $size = 'small'; //default size
    public function __construct($params)
    {
        foreach ($params as $property => $value)
        {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
        // Size is now "large", color is "red"
    }
}
```

You can always re-initialize later like so, if you need to:

```
$this->load->library('Someclass');
$this->Someclass->__construct($params);
```

Another thing to note is that if you have a config file that matches the name of your class, that configuration will be loaded automatically. So for example, if you have the file `application/config/someclass.php`:

```
$config['size'] = 'medium';
$config['color'] = 'green';
// etc.
```

This config will be automatically passed to the class constructor of "someclass" when it is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

In libraries directory create one file `Someclass_lib.php`

Here is your Library code

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Someclass_lib
{
    public  $type       =   '';
    public  $color      =   '';

    function Someclass_lib($params)
    {
        $this->CI   =&  get_instance();
        $this->type =   $params['type'];
        $this->color    =   $params['color'];
    }
}
```

Use this code when you want to load library

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red'); 
$this->load->library('Someclass_lib', $params);
```